# Android table layout empty cells border and weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

For my android application I need to create table layout composed from cells of different colors divided by black border. Cells should be empty, only background color. I do it as below however there are no border appear and the horizontal division is incorrect. It looks like 3 equal cells and not as per layout_weight 0.25/0.25/0.5. Anybody can advise?

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:background="#000000">


    <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow5_11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp" 
            android:dividerPadding="5dp"
            android:background="#000000">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#00FF00"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"/>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#00FF00"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
                    />
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp"/> 

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5_11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not, but thanks anyway. I found the problem. It is not related to the code above but there was an exception before the table.